# The sides of a triangle are in the ratio $1:\sqrt 3: 2$, then the angles are in the ration-

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Using the sine rule

$$\sin A:\sin B:\sin C=1:\sqrt 3: 2$$

This is small question, so I could only do one step. How should finish it?

Comment: Note that $1^2+(\sqrt{3})^2=2^2$. So, by Pythagoras, the angle opposite to the side $2$ is $\pi/2$. Therefore, you can glue two copies of this triangle along the side of length $\sqrt{3}$ and get a new triangle with all sides of length $2$. From that you get that the other two angles are $\pi/3$ and $\pi/6$.

Comment: There isn't enough context to tell us how much of an explanation as to why the answer is $1:2:3$ you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer is in comment. In any case it is simpler to find the angles themselves and use the result to find the ratio.

In general case  use the cosine theorem to find the angles in a triangle:
$$
\cos A=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}.
$$
In your case one obtains: 
$$
\cos A=\frac{\sqrt3}2,\;\cos B=\frac12,\; \cos C=0.
$$
I assume the angles with these cosines are well-known to you.

Answer (score 0):

In a triangle, given that $$a=k, b=\sqrt{3} k, c=2k \implies c^2=a^2+b^2, ~\text{so}~ C=\pi/2$$ 
Next, bt sin-law:
$$\frac{\sin A}{1}=\frac{\sin B}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\sin C}{2} \implies \frac{\sin A}{1/2}=\frac{\sin B}{\sqrt{3}/2}=\frac{\sin C}{1} \implies A=\pi/6, B=\pi/3, C=\pi/2.$$ Also check that $A+B+C=\pi.$
So $$A:B:C:=1:2:3$$

Comment: Please see my edit.